# uncountable product of two-point discrete space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I know that uncountably product of $\{0,2\}$ is not-metrizable, separable, compact, Hausdorff and not second countable. But what we can say about [Lindelöf property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space)? I think it is not Lindelöf, but how can I show it? Could you give me any idea?

Comment: If by lindelof property, you mean wether it is a lindelof space, then the answer is trivially yes. Compactness implies lindelof.

Comment: oh, yes, I have to sleep, so sorry.

Comment: Not all uncountable products of a 2-point space are separable (you need at most continuum many copies). All such spaces are ccc though.

Answer (score 5):

It is obviously Lindelöf (every open cover has a countable subcover) as it is already compact (every open cover has a finite subcover). It is not hereditarily Lindelöf, nor hereditarily separable, as the subspace of all points with exactly *one* coordinate equal to 2 (and all others 0) is discrete and uncountable, and so not Lindelöf and not separable.